# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll (SqlTransaction)

Tags: c#, transactions, sapb1

Additional information invalid transaction closed the connection
Hello. I am developing a project to be used in SAP B1. I want to transfer rows from one table to another and delete these transferred rows from the table above. This process is taking place.

I want to save the rows transferred to the sub-table to a user-defined field in SAP with a button later. But I'm getting the error in the title on this line:

SqlTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

Here is my codes:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = *.***.***.**; Initial Catalog = SBODemoTR; User ID = sa ; Password = ******10601");
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT T0.[CardName] AS 'MÜŞTERİ', T0.[DocNum] AS 'SİPARİŞ NO', T1.[ItemCode] AS 'SATIŞ NO', T1.[Dscription] AS 'KALEM TANIMI', T0.[DocDueDate] AS 'PLANLANAN TESLİM TARİHİ', T1.[Quantity] AS 'SİPARİŞ MİKTARI' FROM ORDR T0  INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] WHERE T0.[DocStatus] = 'O' ", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = false; // Select butonlarının seçili olmadan gelmesini sağlar.   
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["MÜŞTERİ"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["SİPARİŞ NO"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["SATIŞ NO"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["KALEM TANIMI"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["PLANLANAN TESLİM TARİHİ"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["SİPARİŞ MİKTARI"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

.......

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        string constring = @"Data Source = *.***.***.**; Initial Catalog = SBODemoTR; User ID = sa ; Password = *******01";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO @ODS_HFTURETIM ([MÜŞTERİ], [SİPARİŞ NO], [SATIŞ NO], [KALEM TANIMI], [PLANLANAN TESLİM TARİHİ], [SİPARİŞ MİKTARI])VALUES(@MÜŞTERİ, @SİPARİŞ NUMARASI, @SATIŞ NUMARASI, @KALEM TANIMI, @PLANLANAN TESLİM TARİHİ, @SİPARİŞ MİKTARI])", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MÜŞTERİ", row.Cells["MÜŞTERİ"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SİPARİŞ NUMARASI", row.Cells["SİPARİŞ NUMARASI"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SATIŞ NUMARASI", row.Cells["SATIŞ NUMARASI"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KALEM TANIMI", row.Cells["KALEM TANIMI"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLANLANAN TESLİM TARİHİ", row.Cells["PLANLANAN TESLİM TARİHİ"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SATIŞ MİKTARI", row.Cells["SATIŞ MİKTARI"].Value);
                    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            transaction.Commit();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Başarılı Bir Şekilde Kaydedildi!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        
    }
```

[FillData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq4HI.png)

[FillData2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKVNw.png)

Comment: Use only one connection.  You have 'new' in tow places and you should only have one connection in the app.

Comment: At top of code after InitializeComponent(); you are creating a connection when the form is constructed.  So you do not need to create a new connection in the button4_Click event.  The first con is global and will be recognized inside the click event

Comment: Yes, I did these, but now it says the column named MÜŞTERİ cannot be found.

Comment: Put a break point after fill(dt).  The hover over variable dt and use the pulldown arrow and select Data Visualizer.  Check column names to be sure they are the same.

Comment: yes i did but i couldn't reach data visualizer

Comment: When you hover over dt you will see a triangle (upside down) to the right of the dt.  Click on triangle.

Comment: I'm adding a picture. 
no arrow sign It name is FillData

Answer (score 0):

This is the picture you should see :

[image]

Comment: I cant see it. Why do you think?

Comment: Your picture is showing DataTable and mine isn't. I think you have to hover a little more to the right.  You have to put break point after the Fill. Move break point down one line.

Comment: i try everything but i can't access the image you mentioned. I would be very grateful if you could help me find another way to do this.

Comment: Did you move breakpoint down one line?  dt doesn't get filled until after the instruction is executd.

Comment: I'm adding a new picture. I moved break point.

Comment: What happens if you hover over dt?  Is dt null?  then the query to database is failing.  Does DGV show results?

Comment: this database is actually a user-defined field that I created in SAP. The column names match the column names in my project. I'm typing by looking at the column names in SAP but it still says field not found

Comment: Is the DGV getting filled?  If the dt is null than you could get the failure.  It may not be finding any of the column names and just failing when the first column data is read.  Try commenting out the first column and see if you get same issue with other columns.

Comment: I can not. It is not working all kinds.

Comment: There is something wrong with the connection or query.  Best thing to do is to check the database logs.  If you use SQL Server Management Studio and look under the Management tab in the explorer you will find the log files.  Search the logs around the time the app failed.  The server may have more than one database attached and you are failing because you are connecting to wrong database.  Or the credentials are failing.  You may only have read permission to the table you are trying to write.